# "unexpected metadata layout" - Django-cities

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-migrations, spatial-query

I want my project to serve all world cities by using [Django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities).

First and after facing many problems, I made my SQLite accept spacial queries by using advice in this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787700/unable-to-locate-the-spatialite-library-django/39881926#39881926).

So far I can run "makemigrations" but when I run "migrate" I receive: `unexpected metadata layout`.

I think the answer to my problem is included in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761089/cannot-create-column-with-spatialite-unexpected-metadata-layout) but I'm not sure how to apply it in a Django project.

This is full text of the error when I run "migrate":

```
 Applying cities.0001_initial...AddGeometryColumn() error: unexpected metadata layout
CreateSpatialIndex() error: "no such table: geometry_columns"
AddGeometryColumn() error: unexpected metadata layout
CreateSpatialIndex() error: "no such table: geometry_columns"
AddGeometryColumn() error: unexpected metadata layout
CreateSpatialIndex() error: "no such table: geometry_columns"
AddGeometryColumn() error: unexpected metadata layout
CreateSpatialIndex() error: "no such table: geometry_columns"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\spatialite\schema.py", line 102, in add_field
    super(SpatialiteSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 160, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 128, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 98, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table cities_city__new has no column named location
```